# trust vs 'trust to'

Tags: grammaticality, word-choice, difference

> As, by convention, the government is drawn from the party controlling a majority
>   in the House of Commons, it can effectively decide what policies it wishes to implement
>   and **trust to** its majority to ensure that its proposals become law.

Source: p 80, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

> [1.5](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trust):
>   **trust to** = [no object]  Place reliance on (luck, fate, or chance):

I still can't differentiate this definition from just **trust**; what are the similarities and differences?
 Must **trust to** must be used here? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, lets boil the sentence down to the question at hand.

> **Choice A:** The House can decide which policies to trust to its majority to ensure...
>
> **Choice B:** The House can decide which policies to trust its majority to ensure...

For choice A, "trust to" would be better and more clearly stated as "entrust to."

> **entrust**: Assign the responsibility for doing something to (someone):
> [source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entrust)

In this case, the majority is assigned the responsibility of policy implementation.

For choice B, the given definition of trust applies. In this case, the House isn't "entrusting" the majority with a specific task (here being policy implementation). The House is instead declaring general reliance on the majority to do their job (which includes policy implementation but also other things).